# PayPal is not returning success parameters for LIVE account

Tags: java, spring-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal payment sandbox account works fine but when i switch to LIVE, redirection on success URL is happening but success data parameters like amount,transaction id etc. are not coming along with success URL.

**NOTE: PDT is enabled as redirection is happening , and the problem is with only with LIVE.**

Do i need to do any special treatment for LIVE account? or I am missing any setting from PayPal side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the application i was working on was a **multi-tenant** application so i had to decide that on which tenant PayPal success redirection should happen. So to do that i was overriding `item-name` parameter of PayPal to send the `tenant-id` and that was the problem. PayPal will apply additional security when it comes to live account.